# How many pairs of diagonals of of a odd sided regular polygon intersect within the interior the polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

How many pairs of diagonals of a $2n+1$ sided regular polygon intersect within the interior of the polygon?

(By interior I mean it shouldn't intersect on the vertex)

For a triangle there is no diagonal.

For a Pentagon five pair of  diagonals intersect inside the interior of the Pentagon.

For a heptagon there are so many diagonals that I got confused.

Can someone help me out.

Comment: This might be helpful --> http://www.wikihow.com/Find-How-Many-Diagonals-Are-in-a-Polygon

Comment: All of them intersect at least one other diagonal.  What are you really asking?

Comment: Are you asking how many (unordered pairs) of diagonals intersect in the interior of the polygon? That is an interesting question with a suprisingly short answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I am exactly asking the same. I wrote in the question it intersect inside the polygon.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, they surely do intersect with sides, which is quite obvious. My question was how many pairs of diagonals intersect within the interior of the polygon.

Comment: @Babai:  Thank you. Regrettably the question was closed. It is fairly easy to avoid closure, by giving some indication of what one has tried. If the question is reopened, or comes up again, and I notice that has happened, I will write an answer. But not until  tomorrow, it is quite late here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you, you can vote for a reopen . :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's open now. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to count. This is the quickest I know.

**Choose** $4$ vertices from the $2n+1$ available. *Exactly* one pair of diagonals determined by dividing these vertices into two pairs meet in the interior of the polygon.

Thus the required number of pairs of diagonals is $\binom{2n+1}{4}$.